# Snackbar recomposing multiple times on navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So NavHost recomposes my screen a lot of times (I'm thinking that is every frame of the animation) and this is triggering my showSnackBar lambda like 5 times , sometimes even more, I'm trying to propagate it from the composable itself to the MainActivity which shows the snackbar, but this is recomposed multiple times.

```
NavHost(...) {

 composable(NavigationScreens.ProfileScreen.route, enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }, exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }) {
            trackScreen(NavigationScreens.ProfileScreen.route)
            val viewModel: ProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
            ProfileScreen(
                uiState = uiState,
                onNavigateBackToLogin = {
                    navController.navigate(NavigationScreens.LoginGraph.route) {
                        popUpTo(NavigationScreens.ProfileScreen.route) {
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                },
                showSnackBarMessage = showSnackBarMessage,
              
            )
        }
}
```

Seems like when I navigate to another composable, the  `showSnackBarMessage = showSnackBarMessage` is triggered multiple times

I don't want to live the Snackbar inside the ProfileScreen, instead I'm looking to propagate it to the `MainActivity` which I use it like

```
Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = appState.scaffoldState,
                    topBar = { TopAppBarComposable(navController = navController) },
                    bottomBar = { BottomBarNavigation(navController = navController) },
                    backgroundColor = Color.Black
                ) {
                    NavigationGraph(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding()),
                        navController = navController,
                        showSnackBarMessage = { message, showError, duration ->
                            appState.showSnackbar(message = message, error = showError, duration = duration)
                        }
                    )
                }
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You can call LaunchedEffect(showSnackBarMessage){} which only will trigger once. If you wish to update it every time it set you can create a class, not a data class, since LauchedEffect or remember under the hood checks equals so every time you set a new class you can trigger a new launch

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Thracian answer, I added this LaunchedEffect inside each Screen composable that propagated the snackBarMessage, since the recomposition happens on every frame after navigating to another screen, which executes again each screen composable.

```
    var snackBarMessage by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                SnackBarMessage(
                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Short,
                    message = "",
                    isError = false
                )
            )
        }
    
        if (snackBarMessage.message.isNotEmpty()) {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = snackBarMessage.message) {
                showSnackbarMessage.invoke(
                    snackBarMessage.message,
                    snackBarMessage.isError,
                    snackBarMessage.duration
                )
            }
        }

class SnackBarMessage(val duration: SnackbarDuration, val message: String, val isError: Boolean)
```